# how to insert/update data in sql database using azure databricks notebook jdbc

Tags: sql-update, azure-sql-database, sql-insert, azure-databricks

I got lots of example to append/overwrite table in sql from AZ Databricks Notebook. But no single way to directly update, insert data using query or otherway.

ex. I want to update all row where (identity column)ID = 1143, so steps which I need to taken care are

```scala
val srMaster = "(SELECT ID, userid,statusid,bloburl,changedby FROM SRMaster WHERE ID = 1143) srMaster"
val srMasterTable = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=srMaster, 
   properties=connectionProperties)
srMasterTable.createOrReplaceTempView("srMasterTable")
val srMasterTableUpdated = spark.sql("SELECT userid,statusid,bloburl,140 AS changedby FROM srMasterTable")
    
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
srMasterTableUpdated.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .jdbc(jdbcUrl, "[dbo].[SRMaster]", connectionProperties)
```

Is there any other sufficient way to achieve the same.

Note : Above code is also not working as `SQLServerException: Could not drop object 'dbo.SRMaster' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.` , so it look like it drop table and recreate...not at all the solution.

Comment: Do you wish to insert new data into table or copy data from another table when a column (ID ) matcher your value (1143) ?

Comment: Hi, I think this link(https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/10/12/executing-sql-server-stored-procedures-on-databricks-pyspark) will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use insert using a FROM statement.

Example: **update values from another table in this table where a column matches.**

```
INSERT INTO srMaster
     FROM srMasterTable SELECT userid,statusid,bloburl,140 WHERE ID = 1143;
```

or

**insert new values to rows where one of the existing column value matches**

```
UPDATE srMaster SET userid = 1, statusid = 2, bloburl = 'https://url', changedby ='user' WHERE ID = '1143'
```

or   **just insert multiple values**

```
INSERT INTO srMaster VALUES
    (1, 10, 'https://url1','user1'),
    (2, 11, 'https://url2','user2');
```

In SQL Server, you cannot drop a table if it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. You have to either drop the child tables before removing the parent table, or remove foreign key constraints.

For a parent table, you can use the below query to get foreign key constraint names and the referencing table names:

```
   SELECT name AS 'Foreign Key Constraint Name', 
           OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS 'Child Table'
   FROM sys.foreign_keys 
   WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id) = 'dbo' AND 
              OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) = 'PARENT_TABLE'
```

Then you can alter the child table and drop the constraint by its name using the below statement:

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.childtable DROP CONSTRAINT FK_NAME;
```